# How to get proportions in R using table function?

Tags: r

I have a crime dataset having few variables as (ID,Year,Date,Arrest) , now I am trying to get the proportion of Arrests made in a particular year for example for years say (2001,2010,2015) how can I calculate it by using table function?

I tried using below code, but it doesn't give a decent outcome :

```
prop.table(table(CRDATA$Year,CRDATA$Arrest))
```

and

```
prop.test(table(CRDATA$Year,CRDATA$Arrest))
```

Note: dataset name is CRDATA, Year is of Date type and Arrest is of Logi datatype

Below is a portion of dataset

```
ID      Date           Location Arrest  Area    Year
8951354 12/31/12 23:15  STREET  FALSE   69  2012
8951141 12/31/12 22:00  STREET  FALSE   24  2012
8952745 12/31/12 22:00  YARD    FALSE   11  2012
8952223 12/31/12 22:00  STREET  FALSE   67  2012
8951608 12/31/12 21:30  STREET  FALSE   35  2012
8950793 12/31/12 20:30  STREET  TRUE    19  2012
8950760 12/31/12 20:10  STREET  FALSE   48  2012
8951611 12/31/12 20:00  STREET  FALSE   40  2012
8951802 12/31/12 19:00  STREET  TRUE    29  2012
```

Comment: please share a small example dataset that will make your code reproducible, along with expected output.

Comment: Hi @mtoto, sorry for providing incomplete data, I wish i could explain myself better than this. I am new to R and trying my best to catch up things asap !

Comment: No probs, can you show expected output as well please?

Comment: What does *it doesn't give a decent outcome* mean, and what *is* a decent outcome for you?

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify what you want (total, rows, columns):

```
set.seed(123)
dat=data.frame(Year=rep(2001:2010,10),Var=rnorm(100,200,50)>198)
prop.table(table(dat$Year,dat$Var)) #% of total

       FALSE TRUE
  2001  0.04 0.06
  2002  0.06 0.04
  2003  0.05 0.05
  2004  0.04 0.06
  2005  0.06 0.04
  2006  0.03 0.07
  2007  0.03 0.07
  2008  0.05 0.05
  2009  0.05 0.05
  2010  0.06 0.04
prop.table(table(dat$Year,dat$Var),1) #% rows

       FALSE TRUE
  2001   0.4  0.6
  2002   0.6  0.4
  2003   0.5  0.5
  2004   0.4  0.6
  2005   0.6  0.4
  2006   0.3  0.7
  2007   0.3  0.7
  2008   0.5  0.5
  2009   0.5  0.5
  2010   0.6  0.4
prop.table(table(dat$Year,dat$Var),2) #% columns

            FALSE       TRUE
  2001 0.08510638 0.11320755
  2002 0.12765957 0.07547170
  2003 0.10638298 0.09433962
  2004 0.08510638 0.11320755
  2005 0.12765957 0.07547170
  2006 0.06382979 0.13207547
  2007 0.06382979 0.13207547
  2008 0.10638298 0.09433962
  2009 0.10638298 0.09433962
  2010 0.12765957 0.07547170
```

Comment: Hi @Robert, I appreciate your quick response, call me a naive or a stupid what not...but I think I need to know a lot of things in R as I can't really understand your answer. Let me re frame my question (to the point) I want to know the proportion of Arrests made in 2010, how can I get it by table function ?

Comment: Then use prop by rows, in the example the answer would be 40%  `prop.table(table(dat$Year,dat$Var),1)`

Answer (score 0):

Indexing is the key. You can table two variables according to the criteria that you need. Consider these data:

```
dt  <- data.frame(gender = rep(c("Male", "Female"), c(4, 2) ), trans = rep(c("Car", "Bus", "Bike"), c(3, 2, 1) ))

table(dt)
        trans
gender   Bike Bus Car
Female    1   1   0
Male      0   1   3
```

By adjusting the arguments of `dt$colname`, you can get a finer control over the final output. I think this is the point that requires attention. Here I want only the people using the car.

```
 table(dt$gender[dt$trans=="Car"])

Female   Male 
     0      3
```

For your case, hence, try to handle the problem with indexing.
Instead of

```
prop.test(table(CRDATA$Year,CRDATA$Arrest)),
```

try

```
prop.test(table(CRDATA$Year[CRDATA$Arrest == "FALSE"]))
```

Comment: I am working on it :)

Answer (score 0):

By the way you have structured your data, it seems to me that you won't get a real yearly proportion **until you summarize by year**. If you go `prop.table(table`-ing rigth away, all you'll find is what each record represent to the whole total (either by total, row or column, as in @Robert's answer).

To summaryze by year:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(CRDATA)
CRDATA[, sum(Arrest), by = Year][, .(Year, prop.table(V1))]
```

The first expression in `[]` totalizes by year, the second one calculates the proportion and displays it along the year.

**########## EDIT ########**

A `dplyr` alternative:

```
library(dplyr)
CRDATA %>% group_by(YEAR) %>% summarize(arr = sum(Arrest)) %>% mutate(prop=arr/sum(arr))
```